# What is the name of this UI Element?

Tags: interface-design, terminology, ios, user-experience

I'm looking for the exact name of the UI card (?) element marked with the red dashed lines here that is often used for product purchases. Does anyone know the name of it?

[image]

Comment: Is it called a card? It basically a tab interface floating around though.

Comment: I don't doubt that some people give it a name, but it's a pretty diverse group of items to have only one name. It's got headlines, product description text, one or more command buttons, icons, bullet points, price, and so on.

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to say?

Comment: Doug... I call it Doug. `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is called a SlidingUpPanel** - given that one has this sort of interaction behavior with the element in mind:

https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel

[image]

Searching for SlidingUpPanel as UI element delivers the best search results as well as the most ready to use components out of various frameworks.

Comment: I guess from a developer's point of view you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Those are simply called "cards" in every environment that I've seen them in. You could add other descriptors in this case, such as "flat", "rounded", and "low contrast" (the text in the images you show would likely fail an accessibility audit). But they are just cards. Searching for "checkout card" or something similar can get you more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I call them popovers. As they **pop over** the content. It's very much seen in the iOS UI.
[image]